# Laravel unit test requires /dev/tty to be writable during build process

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, deployment

I have set up a unit test in Laravel which requires a file to be written and read. This works locally but when executed by a bitbucket pipeline it gives me an error

```
... 
+ php artisan test 
Warning: TTY mode requires /dev/tty to be read/writable.
...
```

Now, I understand that this means that the script can't read or write files, I can't, however, figure out how to tell it to do so.

This is the `bitbucket-piplines.yml` file

```
# This is a sample build configuration for PHP.
# Check our guides at https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/e8YWN for more examples.
# Only use spaces to indent your .yml configuration.
# -----
# You can specify a custom docker image from Docker Hub as your build environment.
image: php:8.1.10

pipelines:
  pull-requests: #trigger on pullrequest, only works when there are no merge conflicts
    '**': #this runs as default for any branch not elsewhere defined
      - step:
          caches:
            - composer
          script:
            - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip git zip libzip-dev libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev && docker-php-ext-install bcmath && docker-php-ext-install sockets && docker-php-ext-install gd && docker-php-ext-install zip
            - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
            - apt-get update && apt-get install -qy git curl libmcrypt-dev default-mysql-client
            - docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
            - composer install
            - ln -f -s .env.pipelines .env
            - php artisan migrate --force
            - php artisan db:seed --class=NewRollout --force
            - php artisan permissions:generate
            - php artisan serve &
            - sleep 5
            - php artisan test
            - curl -vk http://localhost:8000
            - vendor/bin/phpcs --warning-severity=8
          services:
            - mysql
...
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am facing similir issue when running phpunit test in paralled mode in bitbucket pipeline. Locally the tests run fine!